# R unresponsive when executing SQL queries using RODBC

Tags: r, rodbc

For my work, I do lots of sql queries using RODBC package in R. The problem is that when the command `sqlQuery(...)` is executing, Rstudio becomes sort of unresponsive. This means that I can still write in the editor, but I cannot save the script to a file, for example.

I'm running the latest version of RStudio and R in Windows 7.

Comment: R is single threaded, so at a certain level this is unavoidable.

Comment: Depending on the size of your dataset. I've often used `sqlFetch()` and then done the querying once the data is in R. Fetch seems to get the job done quicker on small datasets that require a high level of querying.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Well, the data is definitely too large to fit my RAM. What I end up doing is opening a second session and working there while the first session is waiting for the server to return the results.